# Completely isolating my VM from my host machine

Tags: virtualbox, security, virtual-machine, vpn

I'm scam-baiting fake tech support people (like the ones who ask you to go to 7/11 and buy $200 Google Play gift cards for payment after running `netstat` and saying that you've been hacked). Most of these scammers are dumb, but I want to be safe in case I run into a tech-savvy one.

I'm using a VPN with Kill Switch enabled on my host machine. My VM is configured to NAT by default (I use VirtualBox).

I have done nothing with my VM besides the above. It runs Windows 7 Ultimate and my host machine runs Linux Mint 18.3.

I want to let tech support scammers remote-access to my VM with TeamViewer, or whatever program they want to use.

Have I done everything that I should do to prevent scammers from accessing my real IP address and identifying and/or important information?

Comment: Why do that when you can keep them on the phone for hours acting like you are doing what they are asking, and then continually “screwing it up” and asking them to start over from the beginning. Throw in a few, huhs, what’s, and can you spell that’s, and you’ve got a heck of a good time. A few racist jokes really make for good fun too. They deserve it.

Comment: @Appleoddity If after 5 minutes if you don’t give them access they curse at you then hang up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the NAT network, another party would know your public IP only, not your host computer IP. Make sure there are not open shares, [even the admin shares](http://www.sysprobs.com/disable-administrative-shares-windows-7-lets-data-secret) (with $ sign) available on the host machine (to be in safe side). Otherwise, everything would be safe. Whatever they do, it will on the VM disk only.

Comment: Thanks. How would I do this on Linux Mint 18.3, since that's what my host machine runs?